# Angular strange UI binding bahavior for Date

Tags: angular

I have a strange issue with UI binding when I tried to bind a date object into UI. Essentially I am trying to change date value in the UI using a click event. Number and String works fine but not date. I have put the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxpjwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html

As you can see the change is not triggered for date field (currentDate) when clicked on the button. However, if you remove the `<br />` next to it as below, everything will work fine.

```
{{currentDate}}
{{currentName}}<br />
{{currentNumber}}<br />
<button (click)="change()">Change Values!</button>
```

I have tried putting the button in between the fields as well. The following did not work

```
{{currentDate}}
<button (click)="change()">Change Values!</button>
{{currentName}}<br />
{{currentNumber}}<br />
```

I observed that the date binding is processed/refreshed only when it is placed adjacent to the other fields!

Is this a bug or is there any technical reason behind this?

Comment: Strange issue indeed. But giving `{{currentDate.toString()}}` seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @NiK648, it works if you change the way date is changed as well. If you assign new value using new Date(...) it will work. I used this as the work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [trotyl](https://github.com/trotyl),

Expected behavior. You're binding currentDate to view and currentDate wasn't changed at all.
There won't be a recursive deep compare for object values.

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22604